# Is there a way to determine if a top level Qt window has been moved?

Tags: c++, qt, window-management

I am trying to determine when the main window of my application has been moved. The main window is a standard QMainWindow and we've installed an eventFilter on the QApplication to look for moveEvents for the QMainWindow, but none are being triggered. For a variety of reasons, subclassing the QMainWindow isn't really an option.

Any thoughts on this, aside from starting a QTimer tto constantly check the position, would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's better to install the event filter at the top-level window, instead of the application. However, if you still do not get `QMoveEvent`s and you're working on Windows, you probably can override `winEventFilter()` and wait for `WM_MOVE`. Similar functionality might be available for Linux and Mac.

I usually do not recommend to break the platform-independence, but sometimes it might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing is really the best solution :-/

In the class that implements your top level windows you just overload this function:

```
virtual void moveEvent ( QMoveEvent * event )
```

From the documentation:

> This event handler can be
>   reimplemented in a subclass to receive
>   widget move events which are passed in
>   the event parameter. When the widget
>   receives this event, it is already at
>   the new position.
>
> The old position is accessible through
>   QMoveEvent::oldPos().

This should allow you to detect if your main window has moved. **Why can't you subclass?** Are you using an instance of `QMainWindow` directly? The usual use case is to subclass it anyway.

Comment: The main window class of interest is part of a separately maintained set of code and as such can't trivially be subclassed to solve this problem.